# Using default argument values in Scala UDF from pyspark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-sql

I have a UDF defined in Scala with a default argument value like so:

```scala
package myUDFs

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF3

class my_udf extends UDF3[Int, Int, Int, Int] {

  override def call(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int = 6): Int = {
    c*(a + b)
  }
}
```

I then build this appropriately with `build clean assembly` (can provide more build details if needed) and extract the jar `myUDFs-assembly-0.1.1.jar` and include that in my Spark configuration in Python:

```py
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import IntType

spark_conf = SparkConf().setAll([
    ('spark.jars', 'myUDFs-assembly-0.1.1.jar')
])

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName('my_app') \
    .config(conf = spark_conf) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.udf.registerJavaFunction(
    "my_udf", "myUDFs.my_udf", IntType()
)
```

But, when I try to leverage the default, I'm rebuffed:

```py
spark.sql('select my_udf(1, 2)').collect()
```

> AnalysisException: 'Invalid number of arguments for function my_udf. Expected: 3; Found: 2; line x pos y'

Is it not possible to have a UDF with a default value like this? The output should be `6*(1+2) = 18`.

Comment: @user10465355 thanks, I've filed https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26331; perhaps will be possible someday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at the call chain there is no chance for the default argument to be recognized here.

- Python `registerJavaFunction` [invokes its JVM `UDFRegistration.registerJava`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/927e527934a882fab89ca661c4eb31f84c45d830/python/pyspark/sql/udf.py#L375).
- `registerJava` [invokes matching `register` implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86cc907448f0102ad0c185e87fcc897d0a32707f/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L681-L703).
- Which, in case of `UDF3`, [looks like this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/86cc907448f0102ad0c185e87fcc897d0a32707f/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/UDFRegistration.scala#L785-L797):

  ```scala
   * Register a deterministic Java UDF3 instance as user-defined function (UDF).
   * @since 1.3.0
   */
  def register(name: String, f: UDF3[_, _, _, _], returnType: DataType): Unit = {
    val func = f.asInstanceOf[UDF3[Any, Any, Any, Any]].call(_: Any, _: Any, _: Any)
    def builder(e: Seq[Expression]) = if (e.length == 3) {
      ScalaUDF(func, returnType, e, e.map(_ => true), udfName = Some(name))
    } else {
      throw new AnalysisException("Invalid number of arguments for function " + name +
        ". Expected: 3; Found: " + e.length)
    }
    functionRegistry.createOrReplaceTempFunction(name, builder)
  }
  ```

As you can see, the `builder` only verifies if the provided expression matches the `arity` of the function before the call is actually dispatched.

You might have a better luck with implementing an intermediate API which would handle default arguments and dispatch to UDF under the covers. This however will work only with `DataFrame` API, so it might not fit your needs.

Answer (score -3):

You are passing only two argument while calling the function in spark sql. Try to pass three arguments

```
spark.sql('select my_udf(1, 2, 3 )').collect()
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm afraid that's not the point. I know I can pass three arguments given the function definition, but I _thought_ I should also be able to pass 2 (since the argument `c` is defined with a default of `6`)

Comment: You can initialize the variable "C" inside the function, why are passing it in arguments